# Android PDFBox PDDocument.load error

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, pdfbox

I wish to convert a pdf document into an image using `PDFBox` but when my code runs it errors with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1607): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument


    String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/A8.pdf";

    final File mainFile = new File(pdfPath);
    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(mainFile.length()));

    try {

        //PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(pdfPath);
        PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(mainFile);

        PDFImageWriter W = new PDFImageWriter(); 
        W.writeImage(pdf, "jpg", "", 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, "/myImageFile.jpg");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It errors on the line:

```
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(mainFile);
    E/AndroidRuntime(1607): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
```

As you can see, I have verified that the `pdf` file has content by getting the length of the File.

I'm using the latest library '`pdfbox-app-1.8.3.jar`' and have also tried an older version '`pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar`' but both give the same error.

I added the library to my libs folder in eclipse then right clicked and added it to the build path.

When I expand the library I can see all the dependencies like, **jempbox, fontbox, commons-logging** etc.

Any clues as to what's wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

..PUSH - I can confirm this issue..
The PDDocument class is part of the pdfbox-1.8.4.jar, added to the gradle build and not found in runtime.

EDIT: Stupid me - read the exception upwards, it claims the missing "java.awt.print.Pageable" this lib depends on.. java.awt.* is not available within android.

Solution: Use another library.

Comment: Upcoming PDFBox versions will change this, in the current 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT `PDDocument` does not implement `Pageable` anymore.